# Slicing a str from a str and adding to a list [Python]

Tags: python, string, list, indexof

So I have:

```
text = 'Hi my name is !bob i like to !eat'
```

And I want to create a list that includes the words after the exclamation points. So I would like a function that creates a result that's like this:

```
>>> my_function(text)  
['bob', 'eat']
```

So far all I could think of was:

```
>>> test_string = text['!':' ']
```

but I can't use strings in the place of indices. Any suggestions?

Note: I would like them all to be in lowercase with duplicates included.

Answer (score 4):

I might use a regular expression:

```
import re
text = 'Hi my name is !bob i like to !eat'
test_string = re.findall(r'!(\w+)', text)
print(test_string)
```

result:

```
$ python x.py 
['bob', 'eat']
```

Comment: I am trying to use a different method, if there is one. Thank you for the input though!

Comment: @Emma Pascoe this is easily the most principled and elegant answer here.  If you don't want to employ regex directly, it'd be helpful to mention that explicitly in your post - especially for a problem that is so well-suited to regex.  (In fact, it's arguably true that any solution to this problem will involve regex at some level of abstraction or another.)  Consider including a more detailed explanation of your use case and any edge cases that might appear in your data, to get a response that matches your specific requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` on `!` and then `split` again on `' '`.  Take the first entry from each segment in the second split.

```
[segment.split()[0] for segment in text.split("!")[1:]]
# ['bob', 'eat']
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution [that might not look pythonic ;)] I can think of is:

```
words = [x[1:] for x in text.split(" ") if x[0]=='!']

print(words)
```

Output:

```
['bob', 'eat']
```

Comment: ah i see this is a very clever idea. But how would i modify this if say there was an odd punctuation in the middle or at the end that i dont want included? (ie. say the original string included 'bob%eats' and that got extracted but i only want 'bob'? or 'bob%&' and I only want 'bob'?)

Comment: Well, I can't think of a simpler solution as of now.
But let's give it a try.
With code written above you can extract words. If you want only actual words and not other characters like % or &, you can split these words into array of characters. Then using `.isalpha()` method you can remove unnecessary characters. After this only alphabets will remain which you can `join` again to make real words.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that the symbol you are looking for always directly comes before the word of interest, you can just check if the symbol is in the list of words.

```
text = 'Hi my name is !bob i like to !eat'  
symb = '!'

def my_function(some_text): 
    return [i.replace(symb,'').lower() for i in text.split() if symb in i]

my_function(text)
>>['bob', 'eat']
```

And if you do not want the symbol in the results, just replace it with `''`.